# JBoss Wildfly ClassLoader Issue

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jboss, wildfly-8

I am suffering from a weird problem. When I deploy my application in wildfly it runs perfectly. After a while, I start getting exceptions of type 
interface xxxxxxxxx is not visible from class loader.

The staketrace is as follow:

```
Error Message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface oracle.ucp.jdbc.ConnectionWithTimeToLiveTimeout is not visible from class loader
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.ConnectionProxyFactory.createConnectionProxy(ConnectionProxyFactory.java:79)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1046)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:985)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:966)
    at com.spider.addon.DBPoolManager.borrowConnection(DBPoolManager.java:79)
    at com.spider.addon.DBManager.execute(DBManager.java:55)
    at com.spider.beans.OCGWServices.finalize(OCGWServices.java:55)
    at java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface oracle.ucp.jdbc.ConnectionWithTimeToLiveTimeout is not visible from class loader
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.ConnectionProxyFactory.createConnectionProxy(ConnectionProxyFactory.java:79)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1046)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:985)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:966)
    at com.spider.addon.DBPoolManager.borrowConnection(DBPoolManager.java:79)
    at com.spider.addon.DBManager.execute(DBManager.java:55)
    at com.spider.beans.OCGWServices.finalize(OCGWServices.java:55)
    at java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: take a look in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199732/interface-is-not-visible-from-class-loader

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is in the JDBC driver, include it as a module in wildfly.
Usually i lost jdbc-4 driver loaded in wildfly as a deployment.
Now I put the jdbc driver as a module in wildfly, so the dependencies are shared in all the ear/war that include this dependency.

[try this link](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/installing_oracle_jdbc_driver_on)